# Fast mutation of ndarray (replace part of numpy ndarray)

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for fastest way to replace parts of pre-allocated numpy ndarray.
Below you can see `sim_matrix` (2D ndarray). "For loop" iterates over it *rowwise* and overwrites values given by `levels` (numpy.array).

There are fast ways, which are found:

1. `numpy.copyto()`
2. `numpy.fromiter()`
3. `=` assignment to slice

*NOTE: For simplicity, I assign the **same values on each iteration, it is not the case in production setup**. In actual setup, `levels` contains different values for each row. Thus, using shortcut as `numpy.repeat` or `numpy.hstack` is discouraged as an answer.*

**Are there any faster ways to change parts of ndarray?**

## numpy_overwrite.py:

```
import numpy
panel_size = 365 * 7
rows = 1 * (1+1+2*4) * 10000
# rows = 100
levels = [1778.24] * panel_size
levels_array = numpy.fromiter(levels,dtype='single', count = len(levels))
sim_matrix = numpy.empty([rows, panel_size],dtype='single')

def _copyto(sim_matrix_, level_):
    for i in range(sim_matrix_.shape[0]):
        numpy.copyto(sim_matrix[i], level_)


def _fromiter(sim_matrix_, level_):
    len_level = len(level_)
    for i in range(sim_matrix_.shape[0]):
        sim_matrix[i] = numpy.fromiter(level_,
                                      dtype='single', 
                                      count = len_level)

def _just_assign(sim_matrix_, level_):
    for i in range(sim_matrix_.shape[0]):
        sim_matrix[i] = level_
```

---

## numpy_overwrite_test.py

```
import timeit
import numpy_overwrite as npo
print('_fromiter')
print(timeit.timeit('npo._fromiter(npo.sim_matrix, npo.levels)', setup="import numpy_overwrite as npo;", number=3))
print(timeit.timeit('npo._fromiter(npo.sim_matrix, npo.levels_array)', setup="import numpy_overwrite as npo;", number=3))
print('_copyto')
print(timeit.timeit('npo._copyto(npo.sim_matrix, npo.levels)', setup="import numpy_overwrite as npo;", number=3))
print(timeit.timeit('npo._copyto(npo.sim_matrix, npo.levels_array)', setup="import numpy_overwrite as npo;", number=3))
print('_just_assign')
print(timeit.timeit('npo._just_assign(npo.sim_matrix, npo.levels)', setup="import numpy_overwrite as npo;", number=3))
print(timeit.timeit('npo._just_assign(npo.sim_matrix, npo.levels_array)', setup="import numpy_overwrite as npo;", number=3))
```

---

## Run test

```
_fromiter
=========
from python list: 21.129429172957316
from numpy.array: 61.76275303697912

_copyto
=========
from python list: 52.4522930260282
from numpy.array: 0.7605530479922891

_just_assign
=========
from python list: 52.251478374004364
from numpy.array: 0.6351132979616523
```

Comment: I don't think the `pass` keyword is useful here

Comment: @nicoco I use them to visually indicate end of block, removed them.

Comment: I think it would be better if you then used a `levels` which actually does have different values. Maybe randomly distributed?

Comment: @Graipher then on each iteration there will be an overhead of pseudo-number generator.

Comment: Not in your function call, in your preparation for the test data. As it currently stands, I don't see why what @nicoco suggested should be wrong. You can just pass different levels to the function each call.

Comment: @Graipher the setup above is more about which way i can change **row in ndarray**, but not the whole array.

Comment: So you have shown that copying from an existing array is faster than from a list.  Most of the extra time in copying from a list is spent turning the list into an array.  Compare `sim_matrix[i]=levels` with`sim_matrix[i]=np.array(levels)`.  You've also shown that `copyto` has no speed advantage.  It just provides a few extra parameters that aren't usually needed.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are simply looking for this?

```
sim_matrix[:] = levels
```

*EDIT*: to modify a single row, one should use `sim_matrix[row_id] = levels`

On a side note, beware of [using mutables as default function arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/).

Comment: Nope, values of `levels` will be different for each call.

Comment: And where do these `levels` come from? A list?

Comment: Then why not use `sim_matrix = np.array(levels)`?

Comment: where do you explictitly change **part** of ndarray in this statement?

Comment: If you want to change a single row, just use `sim_matrix[row] = levels`.

Comment: But can you not build a 2D array of all your `levels` for each row and assign them all together?

Comment: It won't get any faster than that. If you really need to use a python for-loop, it is going to be slow. Without more details about what you are trying to achieve, I can't help you any further. Maybe turn to cython?

Comment: @Graipher the whole purpose of this question is to find a way to **overwrite part** of pre-allocated ndarray. If I have all levels at hand, it means they are already allocated in native python list of lists. This is not what i want.

Comment: @CronMerdek In that case, this answer should be the fastest one. It outperforms the other two by more than a factor 10 on my machine. This should be regardless of how many rows you actually overwrite.

Comment: @CronMerdek I was trying to find out what your *real* use case looks like. Because depending on that there might be faster options (like, for example, overwriting multiple rows at once, if you have all the levels).

Comment: @Graipher I have added example of invocation for assignment